# Vue-Dragula not displaying animations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, dragula

I'm just experimenting with [VueDragula](https://github.com/Astray-git/vue-dragula), and that's what I made:

```js
let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#wrapper',
    data: {
      colOne:["hi", "you"]
    },
    methods:{
        onClick:function(){
            alert()
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-dragula@1.3.1/dist/vue-dragula.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container" v-dragula="colOne" bag="first-bag">
          <!-- with click -->
          <div v-for="text in colOne">{{text}} <span  @click="onClick">[click me]</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But somehow, there's just no animation and the dragged element is displayed at the bottom of the list?

[Here are the official examples](http://astray-git.github.io/vue-dragula/)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also import the styles? Not only the JS?

Comment: Oh , no I didn’t

Comment: Wehre can I find them?

Comment: Depending on what you need (scss,
css, css minified):  https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/vue-dragula?path=styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load the styles of `vue-dragula`. Import the styles from the directory `/styles`. You probably want to import the minified css styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-dragula@1.3.1/styles/dragula.min.css" />
```